# filter an API data with current date in javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is example of data from my API look like.

```
const data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Lesley",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-21 20:33:49.04",
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Claude",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-21 20:33:09.397",
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Lesley",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-20 20:31:46.357",
{
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Yin Sun Shin",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-20 23:13:40.41",
},
{
    "id": "5",
    "name": "Claude",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-21 23:13:30.18",
},
{
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Moskov",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-20 23:10:22.863",
},
{
    "id": "7",
    "name": "Lesley",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-19 01:15:26.457",
},
{
    "id": "8",
    "name": "Yin Sun Shin",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-19 19:39:32.233",
},
{
    "id": "9",
    "name": "Claude",
    "creationDate": "2019-11-18 19:38:54.117",
}]
```

i have a list of data that need to display all information in vue-ant-design list. but there is too much of data that make the system lagging. i'm intended filter this data before being displayed. i've tried some other javascript function to display the latest date data but not succeed. is there any javascript reference that i can refer or any sharing that i can refer for how to filter this API data with the latest date in the creationDate? i've no more idea on how to filter this data.

Comment: Are you sure the cause of the issue i.e. system lagging is due to "too much data"? Sorting algorithms for objects like yours, depending on the size of the data, may not be the most efficient solution.

Comment: actually it's not like that, in the same time, this same data also used in my google maps marker in which there are too much marker making the page become too much slower. i observed it with comparing two different account which one only have a little data and the other one has big size of data.

Comment: I see. Is it your configuration of the Google Maps API that makes your application slower or the size of the data? There aren't solutions for a problem we cannot understand or measure. You need to show the objects (functions) that are likely to be the cause of the problem (system lagging...) and if that is the real problem, we take it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best will be to get the `data` from the API ready to show..

But, with JavaScript in the frontend you can do:

1. Sort by `creationDate` DESC
2. Filter elements with `creationDate.substring(0, 10)` equal to first element's `creationDate.substring(0, 10)` in the sorted array

Code:

```js
const data = [{ "id": "1", "name": "Lesley", "creationDate": "2019-11-21 20:33:49.04", }, { "id": "2", "name": "Claude", "creationDate": "2019-11-21 20:33:09.397", }, { "id": "3", "name": "Lesley", "creationDate": "2019-11-20 20:31:46.357", }, { "id": "4", "name": "Yin Sun Shin", "creationDate": "2019-11-20 23:13:40.41", }, { "id": "5", "name": "Claude", "creationDate": "2019-11-21 23:13:30.18", }, { "id": "6", "name": "Moskov", "creationDate": "2019-11-20 23:10:22.863", }, { "id": "7", "name": "Lesley", "creationDate": "2019-11-19 01:15:26.457", }, { "id": "8", "name": "Yin Sun Shin", "creationDate": "2019-11-19 19:39:32.233", }, { "id": "9", "name": "Claude", "creationDate": "2019-11-18 19:38:54.117", }]
const result = data
  .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.creationDate) - new Date(a.creationDate))
  .filter((a, _, arr) => a.creationDate.substring(0, 10) === arr[0].creationDate.substring(0, 10))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can i know why we need to sort by id first? and how about in the API the creation date never be the same cause there are time as well in creation date. that's what making me stuck with this problem.

Comment: I have made code refactor to sort by `creationDate` field

Comment: thank you very much for your solution and sharing. and actually it's better to using substring in filter part `.filter((a, _, arr) => a.creationDate.substring(0, 10) === arr[0].creationDate.substring(0, 10))` i tried like that and it's succeed. thank you.

Comment: Yep, thanks for sharing your comments and improving the final solution!!